# Syncfusion ej2 diagram throws runtime exception after updating to angular 8.x.x

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, syncfusion

A while ago we updated our angular solution from 7.x.x to 8.0.0. Unfortunately we got an exception with ej2 diagrams. Now - after a while we checked again and the problem does still occur with the latest versions:

- Angular v.8.2.2
- syncfusion/ej2-angular-diagrams v.17.2.41

The build is fine, but when we load the application the following exception is thrown in the console:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Node' before initialization
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Node' before initialization
    at Module../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-diagrams/dist/es6/ej2-diagrams.es2015.js (ej2-diagrams.es2015.js:8677)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-diagrams/@syncfusion/ej2-angular-diagrams.js (ej2-angular-diagrams.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/main/main.module.ts (main-routing.module.ts:27)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39698)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

**Update:**
After analyzing the update commit again (which leaded to the exception above) I remarked that I had also changed the **target** option under **compilerOptions** in the **tsconfig.json** file. And indeed - after changing back the target value from **es2015** to **es5** the exception disappeared.

So the question here should actually be why do I get this exception when I try to use es6 or es2015 as the typescript target option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recent version 17.2.47(syncfusion patch release), the problem raised in the syncfusion diagram had been solved.